# trouble processing "java/sql/Savepoint.class"

Tags: android

I am getting the following error I have searched in google but I could not get solution can any suggest me.i have deleted jar files i have went through orderandexport tab tried what everything but my problem could not get solved.

```
Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-01-08 15:08:09 - AMECmens] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2014-01-08 15:09:01 - AMECmens] Dx 
trouble processing "java/sql/Savepoint.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as  Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a  core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable legality. If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use  the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
```

Comment: can any one solve my problem